# Java Graphics

Tags: графика, swing, java, graphics

Доброго времени суток, хэшкодовцы! Даже не знаю, как начать вопрос, в общем, у меня не работает код с Java Graphics. Как я его не крутил, ничего не хочет рисоваться. Нашел в нете несколько примеров кода, там все выглядело примерно так. Максимально упрощенный код:

```
    import java.awt.*;
    import javax.swing.JFrame;

    public class Main{

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frame=new JFrame("Test");
        frame.setBounds(0, 0,400,500);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }

    public void paint(Graphics g){
        g=(Graphics2D)g;
            g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        g.drawLine(20, 20, 360, 20);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы бы лучше для начала разобрались с тем как устроен `Swing`, в интернете есть куча статей на эту тему. но конкретно данный пример надо переписать например так:

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Main{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frame=new JFrame("Test");
        frame.setBounds(0, 0,400,500);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        JPanel contentPane = new JPanel(){
            Graphics2D g2;

            protected void paintComponent(Graphics g){
                super.paintComponent(g);
                g2=(Graphics2D)g;
                g2.setColor(Color.BLACK);
                g2.drawLine(20, 20, 360, 20);
            }
        };
        frame.setContentPane(contentPane);
    }
}
```

Comment: Лично я Swing учил по большей мере на практике(Youtube), так что не особо силен в теории. Мне нужен просто код, который работает. Кстати, в упомянутых вами статьях(одной из них) вообще не упоминается о JOptionPane http://www.sbp-program.ru/java/sbp-graphics.htm#line

Comment: А можно ли заставить мой код работать без paintComponent и всего такого, так как сейчас меня правильность кода не интересует, а swing знаю еще не очень

Answer (score 0):

Проще так

```
package jAp;

import java.awt.Graphics;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class Ap {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new JFrame() {
            {
            setBounds(0, 0,400,500);
            setVisible(true);
            setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            }
            public void paint(Graphics g){ super.paint(g); g.drawLine(20,20,200,200); }
        };
    }
}
```

Comment: Извиняюсь за оформление, не обратил внимание